# What should be the tension for 0.010 inch strings for guitar

Tags: guitar, strings, acoustic-guitar

0.009 inch(diameter) strings are tuned as E3, A3, D4, B4, G4, E5.

Question is, does 0.010 inch diameter strings should be tuned in this tension? When I try to set these like 0.009 inch ones, the tension seems too much. What should be the settings for 0.010 inch set strings?

I am using [D'Addario](http://www.daddario.com/DaddarioHome.Page?ActiveID=1740) 0.010-0.50 string set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should continue to tune to E3,A3,D4,B4,G4,E5. The string set is designed for that tuning -- it's likely that if you inspect the packaging, there will be something to that effect written there.

One of the reasons for choosing heavier strings, is to increase the tension. It affects the sound and playability in various ways (the details belong in [a separate question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/how-does-string-gauge-affect-a-guitars-sound-and-playability)).

0.010s shouldn't feel all that tense - they are still quite narrow gauge. If your guitar is difficult to play with 0.010s fitted, it's probably a good idea to have your guitar checked over by a professional.

D'Addario provides [a detailed set of string tensions](http://www.daddario.com/upload/tension_chart_13934.pdf), if you're really curious.